# A need a recommendation for a book, on test driven programming with jee6?

Tags: java, junit, tdd, java-ee-6

Anybody knows a good book that can help me understand test driven programming and how it is done in jee6? Ive never really used that approach(or at least correctly). I am very curious abut this topic i would like to give it a try in my java web projects.
So if any good literature recommendation, please let me know.

Comment: In this question you will find some good answers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2728360/212952

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a book for that, to my opinon. You need to know, how to create and run unit tests (for different programming languages and frameworks).

The idea of test driven development (TDD) is fairly simple:

1. read the requirements (no requirements -> no TDD)
2. write a test, that tests the requirements. The test will fail initially.
3. write code until the test passes (and don't write any extra stuff!)

Comment: Ok thanks for the advise, i will have a look around the web, i see if i find some examples of tests in jUnit, or something. Do you know any good website with examples and related stuff?